# PanelOLS pandas linearmodels documentation

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linear-regression, panel-data

does anybody know where I can find the full documentation regarding the PanelOLS from Pandas (`from pandas.stats.plm import PanelOLS`) and PanelOLS from Linearmodels (`from linearmodels import PanelOLS`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation for the linearmodels package here: https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/

Answer (score 0):

As pandas `PanleOLS` module is no longer supported you should use linearmodels PanelOLS module instead, with its documentation [here](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/models.html)